# i can't log in and get information if facebook app installed on android

Tags: android, facebook

I have following problem with facebook app.

I have a simple application 'myapp' where you find a simple button 'log in to facebook'

It displays a pop-up where you can type your email/password to log in.

After that, button changes his text to 'log out'

This code works fine if the user does not have facebook app installed on his phone. However,it does not work if user has facebook app on his phone.

I did not find the root cause for this problem because the code works fine if there is no facebook app installed on the phone

Below is the source code:

```
public class Facebook extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    Button post;
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    URL imageURL=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        post = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        post.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postStatusUpdate(arg0);
            }
        });
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText("You are currently logged in as " + user.getName());
                    String userID=user.getId();

                } else {
                    username.setText("You are not logged in.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                post.setVisibility(post.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), session.getAccessToken(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                post.setVisibility(post.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }
}
```

Resource file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```